# $f^{\prime}$ bounded $\implies |f(x)|\leq C|x|+D$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, with $f'$ bounded on $\mathbb R.$ I want to show there exist $C,D$ such that $|f(x)|\leq C|x|+D$ for all $x\in \mathbb R.$

I don't know how to get $C,D$ that works for all $x\in \mathbb R$. I can do it when $f^{\prime}$ is integrable on $[a, x]$, but I realized derivative need not be integrable

Comment: What is diff'll?

Comment: Differentiable. Sorry, topic was too long without abbreviating

Comment: Hint: Use the mean value theorem.

Comment: It's a consequence of mean value theorem ! Let $M\geq \sup_{\mathbb R}|f'|$. Then $|f(x)-f(0)|\leq M|x|$...

Comment: Oh wow duh thank you everyone

Comment: @user476765 why double "L" in the abbreviation when "differentiable" only has one L?

Comment: It's how I've seen professors abbreviate it. I've also wondered this. Thought it was maybe common to abbreviate it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from MVT.

Let $M$ be the bound of $f'$. Then on $[0,1]$, for any $x,y \in [0,1]$, there exists a $\zeta \in (0,1)$ such that \begin{align} |f(x)-f(y)| = |x-y||f'(\zeta)| \leq M|x-y| \end{align} In particular as this holds for any $x,y$, we take $y=0$, then we have \begin{align} |f(x)-f(0)| \leq M|x| \Rightarrow  -Mx \leq f(x)-f(0) \leq Mx \Rightarrow |f(x)| \leq M|x| + f(0)  \end{align} Let $C$ = $M$, $D=f(0)$. Then we have \begin{align} |f(x)| \leq C|x| + D  \end{align} In particular as $f$ is continuous and differentiable and $f'$ is bounded on all of $
\mathbb{R}$, we see by MVT this inequality holds for any interval $ x \in [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $0$ is contained in the interval. So given an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$, consider the interval $[-x,x]$, then we obtain the above inequality. Hence, it holds for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, thank you. Given $x\in \mathbb R$ nonzero, would maybe take interval $\big[-|x|, |x|\big]$ instead of $[-x,x]$, in case $x<0$